# Any way to work in a unique project with different builds to different clients

Tags: react-native, build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a React Native app and five different clients... For each client the app just changes splash screen, app icon, api base url, namespace and app style primary color. I have solved the problem related to different app style using a global variable to change the color... My problem is thinking about the future, when I generate a new version of app with some new feature I'll need to configure one by one changing the image in ~/res/drawable... for app icon and splash screen.

So, my question is: have some way to **work in a unique app source code** and build a new app **without worry about each client app configs/styles** ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo you could try having a different app.json file for each client. In the app.json you can do something like this

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Client-1-App",
    ...
    "icon": "./client-1/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./client-1/splash.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "client": "client1"
    }
  }
}
```

If you then need something client specific in you app you can index it by the extra value in the app.json, like this:

```
const clientColors = {
    client1: {
        COLOR_PRIMARY: '#03A955',
        COLOR_PRIMARY_LIGHT: '#B3E5FC'
    },
    client2: {
        COLOR_PRIMARY: '#1079ab',
        COLOR_PRIMARY_LIGHT: '#1059bb'
    }
};

export default clientColors[Constants.manifest.extra.flavour]
```

Then when you build the app you can invoke client specific app.json files like this:

```
expo build:<android|ios> --config client1.json
```

Comment: Hi Campbell, sorry but I don't use expo =/ Actually I'm working with AppCenter to generate builds, if have some way to do it using this will be great for me... Anyway thanks for your attemption.